# login page redirecting again to login page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

My login page is redirecting me again to my login page and don't know why. I think there have been some issues with my redirect syntax and I'm not able to resolve it so I need your expert help.

My code is below.

**Controller file :** 
Verifylogin_controller.php

```
<?php

// if(!isset($_SESSION))
// {

session_start();

// }

class Homelogin_controller extends CI_Controller

{
    public

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_In');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
            $this->load->view('Home_view', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('Login_controller', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        session_destroy();
        redirect('Homelogin_controller', 'refresh');
    }
}

?>
```

**Model file:** 
Login_model.php

```
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model

{
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**View file**

login_view.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login with codeigniter</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open(base_url().'Verifylogin_controller'); ?>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
    <span><?php  echo form_error ('username');       ?>                   </span>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <span><?php  echo form_error ('password');       ?>                   </span>

     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
     http://localhost/codeIgniter/CodeIgniter-3.1.4/Verifylogin_controller/login_validation
<?php
$this->session->flashdata('error');
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Home_view.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username')   ?>!</h2>
   <a href="Login_controller/logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: File name and class name are not the same. Use CI session class instead manually starting session. Remove closing PHP tag. Show us Login_controller code.

Comment: With such lots of error you did not get any error message? Try to debug it.

Comment: the error it gave in tried to remove them

Comment: @Tpojka there is no login_controller. i wrote it wrong here its basically this <a href="Verifylogin_controller/logout">Logout</a>

Comment: Then fix it accordingly, edit your question.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code, unfortunately. But as for your redirect, try: "redirect(base_url(). 'homelogin_controller');" You seem to have that in some places, but not in others.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Moved my original answer to a comment, as it was correctly pointed out that it should have been.**

You're never setting the $_SESSION['logged_In'] boolean. You're returning TRUE, but you're not actually setting anything. In your login controller, you should set that to true prior to returning anything. This is probably where your redirect problem is actually coming from. That may have been mentioned in the comments, I can't see them from this screen.

Here is my approach. There are some things wrong with it and some things that require some extra explaining. But here's my code:

```
$seg = $this->uri->segment(2);
if (($seg == "login") && (isset($uid)) && (ctype_digit($uid)) && (($uid != "0"))) {
    redirect(base_url());
} elseif (($seg != "login") && ((!isset($uid)) || (!ctype_digit($uid)))) {
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/user/login');
}
```

1. You need to test that the user is logged in AND check whether they're already on the login page. In my case, URI segment 2 is the controller. If they're already logged in AND they're on the login page, it redirects them to the base URL.
2. If they're NOT logged in and they're on any other page except the login page, it redirects them to the login page.
3. You don't need to set the $seg variable. I do it because I use it in other places and I don't want to have to type out the helper code again.
4. I use the Stencil template system, which is why I can use $uid instead of $_SESSION['uid']. I've modified the template code to pass all of the session variables to the view pages. Since you aren't using Stencil, you'll have to figure out where to put this code. I have it in the layout file, so I don't have to check for login on every single page.

**Comments on your code**

5. Don't call session_start() directly. Load the session library autoload config, if you want to use the CI session library. There are some issues with it, so you may want to look for an alternative or roll your own. This would prevent you having to call the session on every page.
6. You appear to be storing passwords in plain text, if this is a direct paste of your code. You should hash the password (password_hash) and store it in the database. Then hash the user's input and compare it with the database (password_verify).
7. You're setting user data with $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_In') then trying to access $session_data['username'], but you didn't actually store the username. You stored the "logged_In" bool.

Comment: You should write this as comment as you are not providing any answer.

Comment: @joe can you give me suggestions how can i improve my code?